# JSP + HTML <table>

Tags: java, html, jsp

[image: фигня такая-вот]Привет) пишу простенький crud-web-service , и вот дело дошло до того, что пользователю необходимо показать, что он там навводил. Одна только проблема: в jsp в цикле я, возможно, чо-то делаю не так, но совсем не могу понять. где и что. Помогите пж(

```
<thead>
<tr class="w3-lime">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Form</th>
    <th>Best before</th>
</tr>
</thead>



   <% if (request.getAttribute("list") != null) {

        List<Pills> list = (List<Pills>) request.getAttribute("list");
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            out.println("<tr>");

            for (Pills pill : list) {

                out.println("<td>" + pill.getName() + "</td>");
                out.println("<td>" + pill.getAction() + "</td>");
                out.println("<td>" + pill.getForm() + "</td>");
                out.println("<td>" + format.format(pill.getDate()) + "</td>");

            }
            out.println("</tr>");

        }

    }

%>
```

Из сервлета я передаю странице список пилюлей(название, действие, годен до)

Таблица получается максимально странной: чем больше записей пилюль, тем больше она сужается, и тем чаще записи дублируются. Получается так, что количество таких "таблиц", всунутых на одну горизонталь, столько же, сколько и самих записей.(

Comment: должна отметить что теги <table> </table> там также присутствуют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка с циклами. Сделайте так

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr class="w3-lime">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Form</th>
    <th>Best before</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

<% if (request.getAttribute("list") != null) {

    List<Pills> list = (List<Pills>) request.getAttribute("list");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    for (Pills pill : list) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>" + pill.getName() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + pill.getAction() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + pill.getForm() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + format.format(pill.getDate()) + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
  }
  %>
 </table>
```

Comment: Оу) спасибо...)